# How to make icon file from pictures (jpg) in c++?

Tags: c++, icons, jpeg

everyon my question is how to convert jpg to ico file, or how to make big icon with high resolution like in windows 7 icon, for example from games Purble place, that can be show at desktop in big view?

Links from tutorials, examples and functions from c++ will be higly respect ..:)

Comment: why would you want to use C++ for that? Use an image editor, that's what they're for. I higly reccomend Inkscape for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using some form of automation, then have a look at [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) --- it's a cross-platform command-line utility that can do file conversions and all sorts of cool image manipulation.